# Fail update database from DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

This WinForms project has the following code:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EbosPr.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From CustCalls ", conn);
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(scmd);

sda.Fill(ds);

DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
this.dataGridView1.BindingContext[dt].EndCurrentEdit();
SqlCommandBuilder myBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);

myBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();

sda.UpdateCommand = myBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
sda.Update(dt);
```

It doesn't update the database and there is no error. How can this be improved?

Answer (score 0):

I have the following code in production in a small internal utility and it works like a charme:

```
public int UpdateSQLDataTable(string connectionString, string TableName, DataTable dtSource)
{
    using (SqlConnection sConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        sConn.Open();

        var transaction = sConn.BeginTransaction();

        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = sConn.CreateCommand();
            command.Transaction = transaction;

            command.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.[{0}] WITH (NOLOCK)", TableName);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            // timeout in seconds...
            command.CommandTimeout = 30;

            SqlDataAdapter sAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

            SqlCommandBuilder sCMDB = new SqlCommandBuilder(sAdp);

            int affectedRecords = sAdp.Update(dtSource);

            transaction.Commit();

            return affectedRecords;
        }
        catch (Exception /* exp */)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you call AcceptChanges on the dataset or datatable.dataset?

Comment: here is how i call your function                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(scmd);

                sda.Fill(ds);
                
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
                dt.AcceptChanges();
                ds.AcceptChanges();
                UpdateSQLDataTable(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EbosPr.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString, "CustCalls", dt);

Answer (score 0):

use a dataTable instead of a DataSet .. that worked for me